# Solve diamond problem without virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, c++14, diamond-problem

Here's the situation:

```
class A
{
public:
  A();
  void actionA();
private:
  int a;
};

class B1
  : public A
{
  ...
};

class B2
  : public A
{
  ...
};

class OrthogonalFeature
  : public A
{
  void orthogonalFeature();
};

class C1
  : public B1
  , public OrthogonalFeature
{
    ...
};

class C2
  : public B2
  , public OrthogonalFeature
{
    ...
};

class User
{
public:
  void run() {
    c.actionA();
    c.orthogonalFeature();
  }
private:
  MyNeededType c; // c is either C1 or C2
};
```

The `User` class needs to own an object that can perform `actionA()` and `actionB()`.

Therefore, I might want to create class `MyNeededType`, which needs to inherit from `A` and (`B1` or `B2`), and I get a diamond problem (the data member `a` is ambiguous). The usual way to solve this is to use virtual inheritance. However, for this project, I CANNOT use virtual inheritance, for performance reason (please just accept this at face value).

So I have a problem. What might help is that the `User` class will operate only on 2 existing classes that I have: `C1` and `C2`. So the other option I thought of was to make `C1` and `C2` inherit from `A`, and reimplement `orthogonalFeature` inside these derived classes, instead of inheriting `OrthogonalFeature`. Therefore no diamond. Here's how that would look:

```
class C1
  : public B1
{
   public:
     void orthogonalFeature();
};

class C2
  : public B2
{
    void orthogonalFeature();
};
```

I like that solution, but how can I then specify the type of `c` in `User` ? It feels to me that I need to create a type, that means: this class is `C1` or `C2`. But I am not aware that this exists in c++?

Any idea welcome, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "own"?

Comment: I just meant it is part of its data member.

Comment: As opposed to referencing one or inheriting one? Why?

Comment: Apart from the always good idea to provide more info, please also consider to see your problem as a XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I.e. what do you actually want to achieve by solving this abstract "diamond problem" in the specific way you are thinking of.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I do not want to use the diamond pattern necessarily. The problem I am trying to solve is how to design my classes so that my `User` class can own a `c` object that is either C1 or C2. I am very open to solution, I just tried to highlight what I (unsuccessfully) explored.

Comment: Exactly as @Yunnosch says. Whenver someone claims that virtual function lookups are too slow by <reasons unknown> I wanna say, “prove it”. If your timings are that tight, you shouldn’t be using function calls at all.

Comment: You still are locked onto the "Y". Try to find/notice/describe the "X": I want to achieve "X", I am trying by using "Y". With "Y" I have a problem. Can you help me solve my problem with "Y"? How about asking how to achieve "X" without talking about "Y"? For that you would have to describe "X" and I am pretty sure that you did not.

Comment: @Yunnosch. Here's my problem, without possible solutions: I am trying to solve is how to design my classes so that my User class can own a c object that is either C1 or C2.

Comment: OK. Please elaborate that with examples. Show two classes which should be accessed alternatively. Take an interface design into account. One which defines both actions. One of each is empty in any specification. Make a template class which assumes the parameter type to implement the interface.

Comment: either make your user a template `User<C1>` / `User<C2>`, or use `std::variant<C1, C2>` and `std::visit`. if performance is an absolute must, do the former

Comment: "However, for this project, I CANNOT use virtual inheritance, for performance reason (please just accept this at face value)."     The only performance issue with virtual inheritance is programmer performance in using it sensibly.    If it is used correctly, there is no inherent runtime performance penalty.    In any event, this strikes me an XY problem, not as a valid concern.

Answer (score 0):

How important to you is fast access to the A data members? Ultimately the virtual inheritance gives you that easy access to A::a, but at some cost to almost everything else in B2 and B1.

Can you get the effect you want of sharing A::a without using the diamond? In the COM model, all interface classes used simple inheritance inherited from the IUnknown interface, but then the instancing class had to implement the ultimate "true base class" function to get to the "registered" IUnknown. There were no data members in that model, of course.

You could trivially set up `B1: public trueA` and `B2: public indirectA`, then in your implementation, have a template wrapper that "activates" indirectA to find trueA. You could also actually have your implementation wrapper derive from trueA, B1, B2 and fix both B1 and B2 instances of indirectA to it?

But note that this relies on the constructors for B1 and B2 not to reference A as it has not yet been initialised.

It is possible to dirtily hack indirectA's constructor to "know" it is actually instanced in C:B2, and deduce C:B1:A or C:A, and you can probably get that reasonably clean by using templates to push the definitions around, perhaps with a little CRTP?